# How to get data from Wikipedia page using WikipediR package in R?

Tags: r, api, mediawiki

I need to fetch a certain part of data from multiple Wikipedia pages. How can I do that using WikipediR package? Or is there some other better option for the same. To be precise, I need only the below marked part from all the pages.

[image: Wikipedia page on Sachin Tendulkar]

How can I get that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What format do you want? I imagine the HTML code of the table would not be helpful...

Comment: @tgr For me data in any format would do. I can get the HTML code of the table but then have to clean the data too minutely.

Comment: ...which means that not any format would do... You can get the wikitext for the template values relatively easily as well, but they can be templates themselves, and not all values come from explicit parameters. So maybe describing what data you are after and for what goal would make it easier to answer the question.