# r programming - webscraping a list of all towns in india from wikipedia.. Wikipedi R package

Tags: r, wikipedia

So i am trying to learn webscraping using R -- and i am using wikipedia website I came across the package called wikipediR.. but without examples on how to use it.

The idea is to use this url
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_India_by_population

and scrape all content out of each hyperlink (town name )

can anyone help or guide towards the right example on this.. i was interested in the package wikipediR specifically but have not been able to get many tutorials or examples on it..

```
Achhnera, (alternate spelling: Achnera) is a town and a municipal board in Agra district in the Indian state of Uttar Pradesh.

Geography
Achhnera is located at 27.18°N 77.77°E.[4] It has an average elevation of 167 metres (547 feet). It is famous for its cultural values; people of different religions live here. There are many temples which have historic values. Achhnera comes under Tehsil Kiraoli. It is reachable through Agra Jaipur Highway. The city is connected by rail to Agra, Jaipur, Kanpur and Mathura.

The temperature in Achhnera is typical of northern India, with cold nights in winter and heat waves in summer. In winter the temperature drops to 1–2 °C and in summer it rises to 45–47 °C. Rain is always good

Demographics
As of 2011 India census, Achhnera had a population of 22,781, of which males were 12,117 and females were 10,664. Achhnera has an average literacy rate of 58.7%, with 65.8% of the males and 50.7% of females literate. Population in the age group of 0 to 6 years was 3,313. The Scheduled Castes and Scheduled Tribes population were 4,890 and 6 respectively. Achhnera had 3665 households as of 2011

Employment
There are few opportunities of employment in Achnera. People travel to nearby cities like Agra, Mathura, Bharatpur for employment. Achnera is surrounded by villages and the economy mainly depends on agriculture. The agricultural production depends on the weather, rains on proper time


Adalaj is a census town in Gandhinagar district in the Indian state of Gujarat.

Geography
Adalaj is located at 23.17°N 72.58°E.[1] It has an average elevation of 68 metres (223 ft)
Demographics
As of 2001 India census,[2] Adalaj had a population of 9,774. Males constitute 51% of the population and females 49%. Adalaj has an average literacy rate of 61%, higher than the national average of 59.5%; with 59% of the males and 41% of females literate. 15% of the population is under 6 years of age.
```

similarly for all towns in the table preferrably in a tabular form.

Is this doable ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to scrape? Can you first few values of your expected output?

Comment: Hi edited the question to show web pages of the first two towns in the link.. also did you get the answer to your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330540/how-to-get-data-from-wikipedia-page-using-wikipedir-package-in-r

Comment: Yes, if I remembered correctly I used `rvest` to extract relevant data from the webpage. I don't think I got `wikipediR` to work. As far as your question is concerned I think it is too broad for StackOverflow. Every town has got their own headings and not all of them match to combine them into one dataframe.

Comment: Hey thanks..  I had the same experience with WikipediR.. Will try using rvest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a homework question ?

As suggested by Ronak, rvest is a better option.. in case you are familiar with html, great other wise would use selector gadget extension in chrome to get html equivalent..

The page you are looking at is not formatted correctly..getting it into a data frame is difficult..  you would need to use html tags..

pseudo code as under

1. define the weblink
2. read the page and store it
3. extract the names of the towns and store it as a data frame
4. create a list of hyper links using the above..(the pattern is the same)
5. create a function which extracts data from every link
6. run function on the list created in 4